# Are there any limitation about the number of sub-folders we can have in sharepoint document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, administration, boundaries

I got a question from our customer about how many sub-folders levels we can have inside sharepoint online document library. now based on my knowledge there is not any limit. now i am not discussing if we should have many levels of sub-folders, but my question if we really have a limit.

Based on my test i was able to create 7 levels of sub-folders, and i uploaded a word document inside the last level, and the word document URL is consists of 264 characters which seems it is also acceptable.

so my question is if there are a limitation about the number of sub-folders we can have inside SharePoint online document library ? or limitation of the url length (where the url length will be increasing as we add more sub-folders)?

Thanks

Comment: Absolutly, it should be right about zero ;-)

Comment: @KasperBoLarsen can you advice what do you mean by  `Absolutly, it should be right about zero ;-)`??

Comment: Sure :-) This sums it up pretty good : https://www.sharepointeurope.com/15-reasons-not-use-folders-sharepoint/

Comment: @KasperBoLarsen ok i got your point now... so u r trying to say not to use them... anyway end users like to group their files using folders and sub-folders, they feel comfortable doing so,,, now on every topic on sharepoint you will find articles saying not to use this option,, but at the end it is the end users preferences and any contributor have the permission to add folders.. now if SP think folders are bad, then let them have the courage  and remove this option from document libraries,, i know  there is an option within each lib to disable folders, but it is set to yes by default..

Comment: @KasperBoLarsen in addition to my above reply..  SP uses folders heavily inside their built-in components, try to add a new modern page>>inset an image inside the page>>check the site assets folders>> you will see that there is a folder created (with the same name as the modern page title)  and this folder stores the images and other assets for the modern page,, why SP did not implement this using managed metadata for example !!

Comment: I know :-) Look at Teams, how are the channels implemented? You got it : Folders  however folders are fine as long as nobody but you are trying to navigate the structure as I hope that it makes sense for the person that created it. Another issue that is more critical is that the max path length is 400 chars, a limit that is reached pretty soon in a 8 levels folder structure.

Comment: @KasperBoLarsen yes the 400 chars is a limit within sharepoint itself,, that can affect folders..

Comment: @KasperBoLarsen also in our case i want to migrate existing shared drives to be inside SP document libraries, and those documents are already managed inside folders and sub-folders. after completing the migration , i will introduce other ways to manage documents (mainly by using managed metadata), but i am sure most of the users will feel comfortable with using sub-foolder, and first thing they will ask about if they can search the documents inside sub-folder, and the answer will be Yes,, then we will end up having the documents managed inside sub-folder, i have been into this for 6 years now.

Comment: Just a suggestion: try using ShareGate to check for any issues ( like the max path length)prior to the migration

Comment: @KasperBoLarsen i already have a licensed version of this tool,, but i did not know that there is an option to check for any such issues.. do you know who i can check this using share-gate tool?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86315/discussion-between-kasper-bo-larsen-and-sharepoint-testdev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [SharePoint Online Limits](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits#service-limits-for-all-plans):

- *A list can have up to 30 million items and a library can have up to 30 million files and folders.*
- SharePoint Online supports URL paths up to 400 characters (SharePoint Server OnPremise only 260)
- You have a list view limit of 5000 items (might get changed, they are working on that), which means that you should not have 5000 or more subfolders within a single folder.

Comment: The last bullet point in your answer is currently misleading. Maybe something changed, but the link you shared does not say anywhere that there's a list view limit of 5000 items. The only mention of the number 5,000 is that you can't have more than 5,000 groups in a site collection, users in a group, or unique security scopes per list or library.

Comment: Hi Dale, it has been almost 5 years, quite a few things changed since then. But have a look at the page that is linked on the limits article called “Manage large lists and libraries”:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59?redirectSourcePath=%252farticle%252fb4038448-ec0e-49b7-b853-679d3d8fb784 - at the start there the list view threshold is mentioned already.